# HTML2PDF - table align css

Tags: php, css, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf plugin with my php script and I encounter an issue to align my table. I did a test with a simple HTML page, and my css works, but as soon as I put it with HTML2PDF, it doesn't work. Does anybody know a trick to perform it ?

Here my code:
I declared my css content like that:

```
<style>
.alignRight {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;   
    margin-left: -200px; 
}
</style>
```

and into my php script, I did:

```
<div class="alignRight">
    <?php
    echo "<h2>Average</h2>";

    $fields_numAvgAmp = mysqli_num_fields($resultMoyLecAmp);
    //Get column names
    $fieldsMoyLecAmp = mysqli_query($conn,'SHOW columns FROM '.$tablename.'AmpliconValues');
    //Columns_to exclude
    $columns_to_exclude= array('Amplicon');
    echo "<table border='1px' CELLSPACING='0' cellpadding='2' >";
    ...
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you set the parent of `.alignRight` to `position: relative;`?

Comment: @Roy, yeah I tried also to set the parent of `.alignRight` to `position: relative`, it has no effect with html2pdf. Table stays stuck on the left. It doesn't moved :(.

Comment: Can you give it just a `margin-left: XXXpx` and try that without the absolute positioning.

Comment: You are not applying .alignRight class anywhere? What does the generated HTML look like?